# Enable UIButton after UIImagePicker is presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I have tried everything or at least I think I have.

I am presenting a custom `UIImagePicker` with a shutter `UIButton` disable.

This `UIButton` is only enable when my view controller receives a notification telling that the camera is ready.

This method is being called; however, when I set the `UIButton` to enable nothing happen. The button is there because I can touch it but I cannot see it.

Here is a piece of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cameraIsReady:) name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)cameraIsReady:(NSNotificationCenter *)notigivation{
    NSLog(@"Camera is ready");
    [self.shutterButton setEnable:YES];
    [self.shutterButton setNeedsDisplay]; //I tried with and without this method.
}
```

Comment: So what should the button look like?  Typo in an image name?

Comment: It is a button with an image.

Comment: Are you sure your image displays correctly? The image should be there even when the button is disabled (it's grayed out then, as far as I remember). Maybe post the code that you use to set up the button. Also, try to bring the button to the front [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.shutterButton] (alas, since you say you can tap the button, that's not the solution)

Comment: Its weird. The action from the button is working but the button as an Outlet is not. I am disabling in viewDidLoad and nothing happens. The button is there but no disabled.